# How to keep text with out changing on Spinner selection in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-listview, android-spinner

I would like to implement a drop down with label "CATEGORY" in android.

Here, when I click on the "CATEGORY" button, then a list should be populated. But, when I select any item in that list, then I dont want to change the label "CATEGORY".

How to do that?

Comment: @m0skit0. If you think that my english is not good or if something wrong with my question then you have the option to edit the question isn't? This is not what I expect answer. This is really embarrassing!!

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? Please do so if you don't want to read such a comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you understand how a spinner works, this becomes easy.  :)

The spinner uses the `getView` method to populate the closed spinner, and the `getDropDownView` method to create the dropdown.  With this information you can create a custom adapter that can have something other than the current selection showing in the closed view.  This also lets you avoid having to have non-data (like the word "CATEGORY") in your data.

A quick example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter { 
    private Context context; 
    private int textViewResourceId; 
    private String[] objects; 

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            String[] objects) { 
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects); 
        this.context = context; 
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId; 
        this.objects = objects; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        if (convertView == null) 
            convertView = View.inflate(context, textViewResourceId, null); 
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView; 
            tv.setText("CATEGORY"); 
        } 
        return convertView; 
    } 
}
```

The rest of the spinner would function as normal, so you could capture the selection in the `onItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: Really thank you very much. Its working perfectly! With out any embarrassing statement you have put code infront of me. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `OnItemSelectedListener` method, get the value of your selection and store it somewhere shared prefs and reset the position using `spinnersetSelection(0);` :) if the spinner is clicked again load the value from shared prefs :)